# install and configure OCI8 to connect oracle to php

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I installed oracle 11g and I did create some tables and manipulate it using sql developer, and I am looking for a way to connect oracle with php on hosting site.

I tried but I get error after using this code:

```
$Conexion_ID =oci_connect($OracleUser, $OraclePassw, $OracleIP);
```

this is the error:

```
Call to undefined function oci_connect()
```

I've known that I should install and configure OCI8, so I downloaded this file:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

but I don't know in which folder should I them to make the connection work well.

Comment: I can give you precise answer if you can specify the architecture and the OS.

Comment: I am using windows 7 and local server wamp, I read in the link that I should edit php.ini by adding this line(extension=oci8.so) but what else should I do

Comment: check my answer. I am sure it should work :) if not do update me on this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the PHP Extension from here(Confirm the PHP Version and download for the same, the thread safe[TS] version):
http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.0.8/windows

You should be able to find three .dll's

php_oci8.dll, php_oci8_11g.dll and php_oci8_12c.dll

Place all dll's in extension directory, in WAMP it is generally `wamp\bin\php\php5.*.*\ext`

open the php configuration from the System try of wamp server and add the line:

```
; Enable only which is required
;extension=php_oci8.dll
extension=php_oci8_11g.dll 
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll
```

Restart the Apache server.

**EDIT** : Sorry I thought the other dll's are the libraries, but instead they are for different oracle versions. In your case enable 11g. Answer updated.

**Update 2016-11-07**: just wanted to say that latest package can be found here https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8. When I wrote this answer 2.0.8 was latest i guess.

Comment: should I put only this line(extension=php_oci8.dll) or I need to put with it the whole path like this (extension=c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext/php_oci8.dll)

Comment: Before that check if `php_oci8.dll` file is present in extension dir.

Comment: only `extension=php_oci8.dll`, `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/ext` will be the extension_dir, php in wamp knows this location.

Comment: I did everything but I still get the error message.

Comment: In command prompt, what is the output of `c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/php.exe -m`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using wamp server on windows than you have to use the `php_oci8.dll` not the `oci8.so`. You need to download `php_oci8.dll` and copy it to `ext` directory under the PHP. If you don't have this extension in your PHP than install it and go to `php.ini` and add `extension=php_oci8.dll`.

Please make sure that wamp server have two php.ini files you have to change it on both the places. once everything is done than check with php info that oci 8 installed or not.