# missing oci.dll and failed to load php_oci8.dll

Tags: php, apache, xampp

i need help in connecting to oracle using oci_connect()
i have installed oracle instant 10g basic on my local machine (running windows 7 enteprise).I also set PATH to c:\instant_client_10g\instant_client and created tnsnames.ora in that directory.i got this error
'The propgram can't start because OCI.dll is missing from your computer'
When i run phpinfo() obviously oci8 is not displayed

Please Help!! Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install and configure OCI8 to connect oracle to php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519686/install-and-configure-oci8-to-connect-oracle-to-php)